# Using Reduce Function in Python To Find Factorial

Tags: python, dictionary, reduce, factorial

Hi I'm trying to write a function to find the factorial product of any given number. For example for factorial (6) I would get the product of 6*5*3*2*1.

so for factorial(3) the output would be 6.

The functions I have so far are:

```
import functools 

def mult(x, y):
    return x * y


def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        functools.reduce(mult(n,factorial(n - 1)))
```

But I keep getting an error that Python is expecting 2 arguments and 1 is given. I know I have to use `range` somehow but I can't figure it out. How do I edit my existing code so that it runs properly?

Comment: do you have to use recursion?

Comment: no. Actually I only need to use range,multi, and reduce.

Comment: so you have to use your own function multi?

Comment: well just swap `operator.mult` in mgilsons answer for your mult, use `xrange(1,n)` and you have your answer

Comment: what is xrange. It doesn't work for me.

Comment: using python 3? If so just use `range`

Comment: nevermind, I figured it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can do this pretty easily:

```
>>> import functools, operator
>>> functools.reduce(operator.mul, xrange(1, 6))
120
```

Note that the first argument is a *function* (you're passing the result of a function call).  the second argument is an *iterable*.  Also note that written this way, no recursion is needed...

<sup>`operator.mul` is equivalent to your `mult` function</sup>

Comment: but what about if it's not in range 6?

Answer (score 5):

```
import functools

def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, range(1,n+1))

print factorial(3)
```

Of course you can use you own multi function instead of the lambda if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

```
 >>> x = 8
 >>> reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, [1, 1] if x == 0 else xrange(1, x+1))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!

Answer (score 2):

```py
n = int(input())
import functools  
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x*y , range(1,n+1))

print(factorial(n))
```

**output:-**
Input
3
Solution output
6

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!

Comment: Other than formatting, this answer is identical to the [preceding answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52257633/3744182) of [Surya Bista](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8548897/surya-bista) answered one year previously.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `2.7`, then I would reccomend [looking here at the documentation for `reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce). If you are using `3`, then we see that 
[functools.reduce is the same as `2.7`'s `reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html)

That is, we see that we need to call `functools` in the same way as in `2.7`. The following is a representation of that:

```
   reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

, which translates to:

```
   functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

For the case of your example, you are making your own operator, which is confusing `reduce`. **This can be solved by adding** `import operator` , and then using the methods that are declared that are defined in `operator` (i.e. `operator.add`).

I hope this helps clear things up!

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import reduce

f=lambda x,y:x*y

def factorial(number):
    if(number==1):
        return 1
    else:
        return reduce(f,range(1,number+1))

print(factorial(n))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perfect snippet for the factorial function using a reduce built-in function. This will print 1 when n=0, as the factorial of 0 is 1.

```
# Read the input as an integer
n = 4

# Import the reduce() function
from functools import reduce

fact = lambda x,y:x*y
print(1 if n == 0 else reduce(fact,range(1,n+1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
from functools import reduce

list_num = list(range(1,8,1)) # instead of 8 put the number+1 of which you need factorial

def fact_num(acc, item):
  return acc*item

print(reduce(fact_num, list_num,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import reduce


n = int(input("Enter a number: "))

print("Factorial is:", reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, range(1, n+1)))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```py
n = int (input ("Enter a natural number "))
n_list = range(1,n+1)
   
from functools import reduce   
factorial = reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, n_list) factorial
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include an explanation? That will be more useful for both the OP as well as future readers. Also, please explain what distinguishes your approach from the accepted answer, at minimum, if not the other nine answers. Are you using new syntax? Does your approach solve problems the previous answers overlooked?

Answer (score -2):

```
-----Import the reduce() function
from functools import reduce

---Read the input as an integer
n = int(input())

fact=reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,range(n+1))
print(fact)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.